# Custom model/data binder for a grpc service

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, model-binding, grpc-java

I'm wondering if there is smth like a custom data binder (from [Spring MVC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder)) or custom model binder (from [ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) )
in the grpc framework?

The goal is to be able to convert a protobuf object (i.e. request, transport-level DTO) into a domain entity.

E.g. instead of this code in my service implementation:

```
public void createCustomer(Protobuf.CreateCusomerRequest request) {...}
```

I want to be able to say:

```
public void createCustomer(Domain.CreateCusomerCommand command) {...}
```

Provided I have a custom converter Protobuf.CreateCusomerRequest -> Domain.CreateCusomerCommand I want to plug it into the grpc pipeline so that the runtime would call that converter to convert the request into command and then call the service passing the command instead of the request.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What we did is that we implemented our own protoc compiler plugin that knows how to convert transport message to entity message. So implementation of the service  looks like `domainService.persist(protoRequestMessage.toDomainObject() )` 
The day will come and it will become open source :-)

Comment: I ended up creating a custom command pipeline. The original .proto request gets dispatched into the pipeline with validation and conversion steps to/from command/protobuf being attached as aspects.